# VBA SQL query with different actions depending on result

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to do a query of a linked table. After I get the results, I need to do 1 of 2 things. Either say it passed or failed. Here is the code I have written. It doesn't give me any errors, nor does it run correctly. When I input a SN I know doesn't have any entries it doesn't run the second part (the fail part).

```
Private Sub SQL_Check()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlMax As String
Dim result As String

sqlMax = "Select count(1) FROM dbo_Event WHERE [AssemblyNo] = 'SYSCHATESTE'   and [SerialNo] = '" & Me.txtUnitNo & "' and [ProcessTyp] = 'SF1';"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMax)

If rs.Fields.Count = 1 Then
        txtECCT.BackColor = vbGreen
        txtECCT.ForeColor = vbBlack
        txtECCT.Value = "Passed"
        GoTo la
        End If
If rs.Fields.Count = 0 Then
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblScannedParts")
rec.AddNew
rec("Inspector") = Me.txtUserId
rec("PO Number") = Me.txtWorkOrderNo
rec("Assembly") = Me.txtAssem
rec("SERIAL Number") = Me.txtUnitNo
rec("DateScanned") = CStr(Now())
rec("Result") = "Failed"
rec("Defect Type") = "Missing ECCT"
rec("Comments") = strFileContent
rec("Qty") = "1"
rec.Update
txtStatus.BackColor = vbRed
txtStatus.ForeColor = vbBlack
txtStatus.Value = "Failed"
MsgBox "Please take unit to NCM Cart for review.", vbCritical, "Unit Not Ready for DOF QA"
txtAssem.SetFocus
End If

la:
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The recordset `rs` is based on a `SELECT` which returns one field, so your `If` condition, `rs.Fields.Count = 1`, will always be True.

Comment: Thank you. I added in a variable. If rs.Fields.Count = 1 Then
    result = rs.Fields(0)
    End If and had the check done based off that. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the recordset `rs` is based on a `SELECT` which returns one field, so your `If` condition, `rs.Fields.Count = 1`, will always be True.

Conversely, the code within the `If rs.Fields.Count = 0 Then` block could never run because `Fields.Count` would never be zero.  And actually, Access does not even evaluate that condition because you included `GoTo la` in the previous `If` block ... which quickly exits the procedure.  Be wary of `GoTo`

If you want to base the action on a count of matching records, I think the logic should be simpler with `DCount()`.

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim lngMatchCount As Long

strCriteria = "[AssemblyNo] = 'SYSCHATESTE' AND [SerialNo] = '" & Me!txtUnitNo.Value & "' AND [ProcessTyp] = 'SF1'"
Debug.Print strCriteria '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
lngMatchCount = DCount("*", "dbo_Event", strCriteria)

If lngMatchCount > 0 Then
    ' do the 'Passed' thing
Else
    ' do the 'Failed' thing
End If
```